# Difference between "mingle" and "intermingle"?

Tags: meaning

How does adding the prefix "inter" affect the meaning and usage of the word "mingle" ?

Comment: Probably very little. *Mingle* by itself already means to interact with other members of a group. Adding *inter* seems superfluous, though some people who like bigger words more than smaller ones will tend to use it.

Comment: This question deserves more credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two terms appear to have come into existence about the same period, the 15th century, and at that time the prefix ***inter-*** entered the English language  from French. They appear  to be just synonyms.

[Inter-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inter-):

> - ***Latin inter (prep., adv.) "among, between, betwixt, in the midst of," from PIE *enter "between, among"*** (cognates: Sanskrit antar, Old Persian antar "among, between," Greek entera (plural) "intestines," Old Irish eter, Old Welsh ithr "among, between," Gothic undar, Old English under "under"), a comparative of *en "in" (see in). Also in certain Latin phrases in English, such as inter alia "among other things." ***A living prefix in English from 15c. Spelled entre- in French, most words borrowed into English in that form were re-spelled 16c. to conform with Latin except entertain, enterprise***

[Intermingle:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intermingle)

> - (v. t. Int.) to mingle, one with another; intermix.

intermingle (v.) (etymology)

> - late 15c., from inter- + mingle.

[Mingle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mingle&allowed_in_frame=0)(v.): (etymology)

> - mid-15c., "to bring together," frequentative of Middle English myngen "to mix," from Old English mengan (related to second element in among), from Proto-Germanic *mangjan "to knead together".

As for usage( [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mingle%2Cintermingle%2C%20mingled%2C%20intermingled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmingle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintermingle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmingled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintermingled%3B%2Cc0)) *mingle* appears to be a more common verb than *intermingle*.

(Etymonline)

Comment: Darn. You beat me!

Answer (score 4):

Check out these definitions:

> [Intermingle:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/intermingle) to Mix or mingle together

and

> [Mingle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mingle): 1) to mix or cause to mix together. 2) to move freely around a place or at a social function, associating with others

Both words mean "to mix." However, the word "mingle" refers to socializing in a group setting. Beyond that additional meaning, I do not think the prefix "inter" has much effect. It comes from the latin *inter*, which means ["among, between, betwixt, or in the midst of."](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inter-&allowed_in_frame=0) Since both words already allude to the "mixing" of disparate parts, the additional prefix is superfluous.

Comment: Indeed, I've never heard *intermingling* used in a social context, and only rarely have I heard of non-social *mingling*.

Answer (score 3):

I've not checked a dictionary, but as a well educated native English speaker, my response is that one would use "intermingle" talking about things rather than people and not in first person.  E.g., The threads were intermingled. I wouldn't say "I intermingled at the party." It might, technically, be correct usage, but it sounds strange and as if one is using a more complicated word to impress.

Answer (score 0):

Mingle sounds like a generic term for socializing in a group.

Intermingle implies two distinct groups that are mixing.

Co-mingle is another term for this I believe, but implies gender more often then not.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, user126374! Can you offer any authoritative support for your legitimate opinion? We are looking for something a little more substantial than personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that intermingle means combining one element with another; whereas, mingle means associating without combining: e.g., in a compound, two chemical elements intermingle and combine; at a party, two human bodies mingle but do not combine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).